# Appropiate analysis for simple survey dataset with Y/N answers

Tags: hypothesis-testing, survey

I'm searching for the most appropriate and simplest analysis to statistically test for differences among 3 groups ("Type1", "Type2", "Type3") of individuals (N=75) according to their answers to a set of 30 questions - the questions are of the type "Do you have any knowledge about topic XYZ?", which are answered Y/N - asked to each individual. In detail, the set of questions is comprised of 3 groups of topics, so there are 3 topic-classes, each with 10 questions. The hypothesesis to be tested are (I) overall knowledge, which could be quantified by summing Y in each "Type", is different among Types - (II) the "kind of knowledge", quantified by the sum of Y-answers within each "topic-class", is different among "Types".
The sample is a random sample from a population of about 1000 teachers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the research questions you wish to answer?

Comment: Sorry, I was just about to elaborate more on the design and hypothesis! Please see the updated Q.

Comment: You say that this is a survey dataset.  Before anyone can provide  you with a reliable answer, you'll need to describe the survey a bit more.  How was the sample drawn for this survey?  Can you tell us more about how the sampling and survey was actually carried out?

Comment: It is a random sample.